# How to implement the birthday formula into python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyqSv.png

So, I'm trying to make a python code that justify this formula above for chance that two people do not have the same birthday

My attempt:

```
for birthday in range(365, 0, -1):
    print(birthday)
```

This is all I got. So above formula put prints 365 to 1, I'm wondering how can I make it so it will keep iterating -> 365*364*363*362.... so on. Any help appreciated.

Comment: 365*364*363*364.!!!---364 after 363?

Comment: You could just approximate it with `1.0 - np.exp(-n * (n - 1) / 730.0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `mul` from the `operator` module:

```
import operator
from decimal import Decimal
result = 1 - (reduce(operator.mul, range(365 - n + 1, 366)) / Decimal(365.0)**n)
```

In Python 3 `reduce` has to be imported from `functools`.

Comment: If i were to put a number like 200 it would output "result too large", i found reduce function still happens though

Comment: it's the 365.0**n that is too large. You could do `365**n` and if necessary (Python 2) cast the reduce to float or `from __future__ import division`

Comment: I updated the answer to use a `Decimal` that prevents the overflow. Still with values over 200 you will get a float presentation problem. The values will get too neer to 1.0 to be presented properly.

Comment: Well you could remove the `1-` to see the difference to `1` in E notation.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain python:

```
def bday(n):
    y = 1
    for i in range(365, 365-n, -1):
        y *= i / 365.0
    return 1 - y
```

Using numpy (slightly faster):

```
import numpy as np

def bday(n):
    y = np.arange(365, 365-n, -1) / 365.0
    return 1 - np.product(y)
```